# Calling one ModalPopupExtender from two different buttons?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I have a panel that is hooked up to a ModalPopupExtender but it can be called two different ways, by either adding a user (one button click) or editing a user (a totally different button click).  The controls on the panel never change, but they are all blank when adding, or they are binded to the data of the particular user being edited.  What should I set the TargetControlID attribute to when I have two different buttons that need to open the same panel as a modal window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of wiring it up via the ASPX markup, you can do it in the code behind of the button event.

```
protected void btnClick(object sender, Eventargs e) {
   ModalName.Show();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the targetcontrolid need to be set to something?  I get an error when it isn't.

Comment: Yea that works.  I just set the targetcontrolid to a button I don't use and show programmatically.

Comment: when doing this, I usualyl set the TargetControlID to some dummy hidden field.

Comment: You can set the TargetControlId to any id on the page. Just make sure the id is within the same updatepanel or you'll get an error message.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to have 2 modalpopupextenders, both using the same PopupControlID for the panel you want to display in both instances.